# How to Pass the Data from Listview A to ListView B?

Tags: android, listview

I have my Cart Activity which contains the items that the user wanted to purchase.

[image]

What I want is if I click the "CHECK OUT" button, all of the data in the cart will be sent to the next Activity having ListView B.

Here is a part of my CartCustomerAdpater.class where i set the textview fields

```
final Order data = items.get(position);
    holder.cart_name.setText(data.getName());
    holder.cart_price.setText("Php "+data.getPrice());

    holder.cart_qty.setText(data.getQty());
```

Here is a part of my Cart.class where my CHECK OUT button is located.

```
checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
        }
    });
```

Comment: *//WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?* ... collect all items and send it to Activity, but it seems like you didn't even tried

Comment: I got a different algorithm for getting those data. but I'm trying to seek for better solutions. I'm learning how Shared Preferences work. I'm just trying to ask for HELP if ever there are people willing to.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose you declared your ListView:**

```
ListView lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
```

*For the case of a listView use `setOnItemClickListener()` , this is my sample code for sending data to the next Activity.*

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ModelClass jhild = (ModelClass) adapter.getItem(position);


                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyApartmentsInformation.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DISTRICT_NAME, jhild.getDistrict());
                in.putExtra(KEY_FLOORS, jhild.getFloors());
                in.putExtra(KEY_AREA, jhild.getArea());
                in.putExtra(KEY_BUYLAND_CODE, jhild.getBuyno());
                in.putExtra(KEY_PRICES, jhild.getPrice());
                in.putExtra(KEY_INFORMATION, jhild.getInformation());

                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

***But my piece of Advice you have to update to RecyclerView***

Hope it works well.

Comment: That is not my case sir. I don't want to click any of the items in my ListView. The "CHECK OUT" button will send ALL of what is inside the ListView_A to Activity_B with ListView_B.

Comment: Try to borrow the same concept

Answer (score 0):

use intent

send

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
intent.putextra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

recieve

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You need to implement Serializable or Parcelable in your **Order.java** class so that you can pass the ArrayList of Order through Bundle or Intent .

       public class Order implements Serializable{
        }

2. Pass the list of items through intent and start new activity

    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(this , NewActivity.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("orderList" , items);
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });

3. Get the list in NewActivity class

List<Order> itemsList = (List<Order>)getIntent.getSerializableExtra("orderList");

Hope it helps!
```